# Laravel parent child relationship, Don't validate self as parent

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

In Laravel, i have `projects` table. A project can be sub-project of another project. I keep this `parent-child` relationship in the same `projects` table.

When editing a project, the user chooses parent project from a select box. However i want to prevent the user from selecting the same project that is being edited; as a parent project. This would cause loops, thus errors.

How can i achieve this? Best solution i can think of is to write a custom validation rule, however, in that case, how can i get the id attribute to check against project_id field? Or are there better solutions other than validators?

I know i can just exclude that project in select box however it is not proper solution, in case someone tampers post data and modifies the project_id value, (setting it to same value of the project being edited), the infinite loop will happen.

**Update**:
Here is my the code for parent project input generation:

```
<div class="form-group">
    {{ Form::label('project_id', 'Parent Project:') }}
    {{ Form::select('project_id', [null => null] + Project::lists('name', 'id'), null, ['class' => 'form-control']) }}
</div>
```

As i stated above, "not including current project id in the select box" is not a proper solution. The application is still vulnerable. It should be prevented in a more proper way.

Comment: Honestly, I would just disable it in the select box. The most straightforward way.  Also you mind posting some code?  Like why would the project_id contain itself, if its supposed to just contain parents?

Comment: It is an edit form. It does not just contain parents. The select box in edit form contains all projects, so user can change the parent project to any of the current projects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It comes out that the solution is pretty simple, just like in every aspect of Laravel.

It is enough to include

```
'project_id' => 'different:id',
```

validation rule in your model. ([Ardent](https://github.com/laravelbook/ardent) syntax)

[Here](http://daylerees.com/codebright/validation) are all validation types with explanations as of Laravel 4.

Answer (score 0):

Just retrieve the relationships without the current project.

```
  $project = Project::find($thisProject);
  $related = Project::where('project_id','=',$project->id)->where('id','!=',$project->id)->get();
```

And assuming you're using blade...

```
  <select name="projects">
  @foreach($related as $r)
  <option value="{{$r->id}}">{{$r->projectName}}</option>
  @endforeach
  </select>
```