# Laravel Relationship: Fetch child and its Parent from same table

Tags: eloquent, laravel-5.4

I have been using Laravel 5.4 for few weeks now. Trying my hands on the Laravel Relationships. I'm trying to fetch a record and get the relation category record. I also want to get the parent of the fetched category using the same relation.

### Category Table:

```
--------------------------------------------
|   id     | name         | parent_id      |
|------------------------------------------|
|   1      | Deals        |   0            |
|------------------------------------------|
|   2      | Dining       |   1            |
--------------------------------------------
```

### Deals Table:

```
--------------------------------------------
|   id     | title        | category       |
|------------------------------------------|
|   1      | First Deal   |   2            |
--------------------------------------------
```

I have added relationship in the Deal and Category Models

### Deal Model:

```
class Deal extends Model {

    public function category() {        
        return $this->hasOne(Category::class, 'id', 'category');
    }

    // Fetching the Deal
    public function fetchDeals($id = false) {
        $deal = Deal::with('category')->get();
    }
```

### Category Model:

```
class Category extends Model {

    public function deals() {        
        return $this->hasMany(Deal::class, 'category');
    }
```

I'm able to fetch the deal and the relation category. But not able to grab the parent of that category.

I tried reading through few possible similar SOF questions:
[similar 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24396840/laravel-parent-child-relationship-dont-validate-self-as-parent), [similar 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27816738/laravel-parent-child-relationship-on-the-same-model), [similar 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34802127/fetch-child-and-parent-laravel-eloquent). But cant figure the relation concept. How do I write the above relation to get both the parent and child category of a deal.

You could also suggest any reference article that I can refer.

Please guide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been on this task for few days now and after reading through few articles and tutorials, I have decided to implement the **[Baum](https://github.com/etrepat/baum#baum)** package

The **[Doc](https://github.com/etrepat/baum#accessing-the-ancestrydescendancy-chain)** is easy with many handy methods. Its easy to traverse and manipulate through and get all parent ids of category. Also, found few helpful videos on the same.

Hope someone with similar requirement will find this helpful. Cheers !!